# Is it technically possible to install Android on an iPhone X?

Tags: iphone, android

I was wondering if it was possible to install Android on an iPhone X ? I saw that it was possible on an iPhone 3GS.

Comment: I wonder how fast android would run in emulation on that hardware. Anything is technically possible with enough time and budget - make get you qualify what solution meets “technically” in your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

No its not, iOS is locked to the iPhone software.